# Aplicar função de autheticação em todas as rotas usando flask

Tags: python, autenticação, flask, jwt

Estou construindo uma API em flask usando flask-restx. Criei uma função de autenticação e aplico ela como um decorator em cada rota, mais são muitas rotas, logo aplicar a função em todas as rotas seria demorado e poderia gerar muitos erros, gostaria de saber se tem como fazer ao contrario e aplicar essa função em todas as rotas e marcar aquelas em que não seria necessario a authenticação.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Podes usar um decorador before_request. Mais info aqui: [Flask: Decorate every route at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164464/flask-decorate-every-route-at-once)

```
_insecure_views = []

@my_blueprint.before_request
def require_login():
    if request.endpoint in _insecure_views:
        return
    # check for login here

def login_not_required(fn):
    '''decorator to disable user authentication'''
    endpoint = ".".join([some_blueprint.name, fn.func_name])
    _insecure_views.append(endpoint)
    return fn

@some_blueprint.route('/')
@login_not_required
def index():
    pass
```